# Conditional format entire column based on value in first cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I looked at all previous questions on SO for conditional formatting and did not find a solution. It could be I am doing this wrong and am missing something simple.

I have a set of column names that are custom date format `Mar-1 (Wed)`. I already applied a conditional format rule to color the column header dark gray based on if the date is a weekend (Sat or Sun). It works as it should.

I now want to gray out those cells in the rows below. How can I accomplish this?

For example:

```
Row 1: Mar-1 (Wed) | Mar-2 (Thu) | Mar-3 (Fri) | Mar-4 (Sat)
Row 2: (blank)     | (blank)     | (blank)     | (blank)
Row 3: (blank)     | (blank)     | (blank)     | (blank)
```

In this case the whole column for `Mar-4 (Sat)` should be dark gray including row 2 and row 3, etc. Right now only Column 4 row 1 is dark gray. What should the rule(s) look like to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

add another role and add the not() function to your condition

Comment: Hi isaac. I have added a visual example of what I am looking for. Thanks.